# Unload php modules on demand

Tags: php

I am wondering if anyone know a way to unload php modules on a per script basis. End Goal is to minimize scripts to use as little memory as possible.

Why? The TOP command shows VIRT @ 279m and RES @ 19m. This is with a script that only checks is a variable set and sleeps for 20 seconds thats it.. I am wondering if I can only load the modules I actually need for the script to run.

I have read in the past this was not supported nor encouraged but that was from 2011. If this is not possible is it better to load modules on demand per script? I ask because I am trying to minimize the size of VM's. Be Gentle :)

Comment: not really a programming issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from 2011 still stands. You could use different php.ini files, but you'll have to make the decision when starting PHP. It also won't bring you much, just try disabling some extension you don't use and you'll will notice you memory consumption won't be significantly reduced.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your response. I could not find out but I figured I would throw it out there.